# Posting comment to Particular news feed FacebookSDK.framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to comment on specific facebook post but i got the below error.

Please help me

```
NSString *myurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/298723893602606/comments?message=\'This is my message\'&access_token=%@",FBSession.activeSession.accessToken];
    NSString  *theurl=[myurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theurl]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError* error12;
    NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error12];
    NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response String=%@",strResponse);
```

Error:

```
Response String={"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_stream","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

Comment: is your "`FBSession.activeSession.accessToken`" valid or is it even a string? make certain it isn't returning nil

Comment: My accessToken is valid.Is API url correct/not?